# Blank string in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int userInput;
    string numberType;
    cout << "Enter a number and I will Check to see if it is odd or even" << endl;
    cin >> userInput;
    if (userInput % 2 == 0)
    {
        string numberType = "Even";     
    }
    else
    {
        string numberType = "Odd";
    }
    cout << "The number you input is " << numberType << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to output the manipulated string value but the string that's output in the last line comes out blank?

Comment: The numberType that you assign in the if/else is local to that block and doesn't assign it to the numberType outside of that block. Remove the `string` declaration type when assigning it. You'll get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `if` and `else` blocks, you are actually creating new variables with the name of `numberType`, and that those new variables hide the original `numberType` you had previously declared. Any changes you make on those variables will NOT reflect to the original `numberType`, as they do not refer to it.

To solve that problem, remove the `string` parts (the types, as having these denotes that you are defining new variables) as you don't want to define those new variables, and want use the previously defined `numberType`.

```
if (userInput % 2 == 0)
{
    numberType = "Even";   // Look ma, no string!
}
else
{
    numberType = "Odd";   // Also here ma!
}
```

With the modified and fixed code, you are now referring to the `numberType` where you intend to put the values `"Even"` or `"Odd"`.

```
...
int userInput;
string numberType;   // This is now where the values be put in
cout << "Enter a number and I will Check to see if it is odd or even" << endl;
...
```

This should now give you the correct and desired output.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're redeclaring numberType. This actually declares a new numberType, since it is in a different scope.

What you want to do is this

```
if (userInput % 2 == 0)
{
    numberType = "Even";     
}
else
{
    numberType = "Odd";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Beacuse you re declared `numberType` this will become local to `if-else block`,In this case the variable local to `if-else` will get modified.So simply use,

```
int main()
{
    int userInput;
    string numberType;
    cout << "Enter a number and I will Check to see if it is odd or even" << endl;
    cin >> userInput;
    string numberType;        //variable local to function .You can modify this variable anywhere inside this function

    if (userInput % 2 == 0) {
       numberType = "Even";     //here you will refer already declared  variable local function. So no need to declare it here again as that will be local to this block.
    } else {
       numberType = "Odd";     
    }
    cout << "The number you input is " << numberType << endl; // Print modified value of string.

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**numberType** the one whose value is updated is local in if and else block.

remove string

```
if (userInput % 2 == 0)
{
    numberType = "Even";     
}
else
{
    numberType = "Odd";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're redeclaring `numberType`, meaning it only exists in the **inner** scope it is declared in; effectively, `numberType` exists only within either the `if` or `else` block. You then print out the original outer scoped `numberType` which was simply default constructed. To fix this, don't redeclare it, but assign it a different value:

```
string numberType;
...
if(userInput % 2 == 0) {
    numberType = "Even";
} else {
    numberType = "Odd";
}
```